How to add value from a row if another row contains a certain value?
I have two SharePoint Lists.
SharePoint List A contains information and gets information added to it.
Example



Name
Title
Age




Bob
Clerk
A


Sally
Clerk
B



SharePoint List B contains information that won't be changing very often.
Example



Name
Department
Email




Jerry
Purchasing
jerry email


Beth
Security
beth email


Joan
Security
joan email



Anytime a new item is added to SharePoint List A, anyone within the Security Department from SharePoint List B must receive an email with information from the row that was just added.
I'm having trouble pulling the correct emails that have the Security tag.

Step 1 Trigger - When an item is created - Item added to SharePoint List A - Good
Step 2 Get items - Gets items from SharePoint List A - Good
Step 3 Get items - Gets items from SharePoint List B - Good
Step 4 Select - selecting Department and Email from SharePoint List B
Step 5 Filter Array - Filter Query is set to Department/Value is equal to Security
Step 6
Step 7 Send an email to those with Security Department with SharePoint List A new item information.

I am stuck on what to do for step 6. Any ideas would be great. I'm open to other recommendations on what to try as well.

An AD group might be easier but failing that, if you want to send a single email with all email addresses then you'll need to loop over every email address and concatenate them all together.  If you want to send an email per person then the loop should have the send email action passing in the current email in the iteration.  Look up the Apply to each action.

other approach: make a Sharepoint group in the site like the site members with these security tagged users, then you can get their emails via an 'Send an HTTP request to SharePoint' action:
{
    "parameters": {
        "dataset": "https://...sharepoint.com/sites/...",
        "parameters/method": "GET",
        "parameters/uri": "_api/web/siteGroups/getByName('GROUPNAME')/users"
    }
},

then extract their email addresses with a 'SELECT' action:
{
"inputs": {
    "from": "@body('Send_an_HTTP_request_to_SharePoint')?['d']?['results']",
    "select": "@item()?['Email']"
}

}
